# ObservableList producing errors

Tags: javafx-2

I made this program that produces 6 random numbers between 1 and 41. In the UI i have 6 textfields and a button. If i press the button the 6 numbers are being displayed in the textfields. I have 1 function(theNumbers()) fired when the button is pressed, the first function makes an ObservableList with the numbers 1-41 and the second function picks 6 numbers randomly.

The problem that happens is that after pressing the button a few times there is an ArrayIndexOutofBound Exception: -1 thrown, usually after (or a few times after) the number 0 is produced (which isnt even in the list) also sometimes a IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4 exception is thrown(the number is random btw). Also it seems to be able to produce the same number twice or numbers bigger then 41.(seen 151)

This is my code:

First function:

```
ObservableList<Integer> list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private void createList(ObservableList<Integer> list1) {
    this.list1 = list1;
    int numbers = 41;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
    }
}
```

Second function:

```
private void theNumbers() {

    createList(list1);
    ObservableList<Integer> finalNums = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            FXCollections.shuffle(list1);
            int lucky = new Random().nextInt(list1.size());
            finalNums.add(lucky);
            list1.remove(list1.indexOf(lucky));
            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    FXCollections.sort(finalNums);
    textField1.setText(finalNums.get(0).toString());
    textField2.setText(finalNums.get(1).toString());
    textField3.setText(finalNums.get(2).toString());
    textField4.setText(finalNums.get(3).toString());
    textField5.setText(finalNums.get(4).toString());
    textField6.setText(finalNums.get(5).toString());
    list1.clear();
    finalNums.clear();
}
```

Any clues to why it does this? Could it be my Acer Aspire One Netbook messing up? To my knowledge these errors shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to remove the exact same number twice ore more in one pass of the for construct. For example you cannot remove the number "2" more than once from the list. The `indexOf(2)` method will return with -1 because it cannot find the value 2 in the list anymore.

So you might check if a number still exists in `list1` before you try to remove from there.

```
    private void theNumbers() {

    createList(list1);
    ObservableList<Integer> finalNums = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            FXCollections.shuffle(list1);
            int lucky;         
            do
            {
                 lucky= new Random().nextInt(list1.size());              
            }while(list1.indexOf(lucky) == -1);
            finalNums.add(lucky);
            list1.remove(list1.indexOf(lucky));

            }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: It's working. :) Sorry for not understanding, but how is it able to pick the same number twice or 0 for that matter, while the second time that double number isn't even in the list? I used a breakpoint, stepping through the code  line by line. The second number it picked was 34, then with list.size being 37 it picked as 4th number 34 again. I looked at the contents of the list before it wants to remove 34, it wasn't there and ofcourse it throws an arrayindexoutofbounds exception: -1. What am i missing here? Besides the do/while loop, or maybe thats it.

Comment: the line `int lucky = new Random().nextInt(list1.size());` chooses a random number between 0 and list1.size-1. The upper bound of that range decreases with every loop you do. But that does not prevent the random number generator from choosing the same number multiple times (if that number is smaller than list1.size - amount loop -1)

Comment: So Random does not pick a number but an index, like list1[30] with the value it holds. Once picked its not part of the list anymore so the index would be list1[-1] value 10. With the do/while loop, saying while(list1.indexof(lucky) == -1 which is true, it savely can remove the value with it's index from the list?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
int lucky = new Random().nextInt(list1.size()-1);
```

Comment: list.size() is 41, an array of the numbers [0]1-[40]41 and gets updated to 40 when list1.remove(indexof(lucky)) is invoked.